# How do I test manual DB transaction code in Django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, transactions

I'm transferring data from a legacy system into Django. In order to ensure the current database's integrity, I'm committing everything manually.

However, when writing unit tests, the transactions won't rollback properly. Since `TestCase` is probably using transactions, is there any way to properly test code in Django that relies on transactions?

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def import_records():
    # initial prep
    try:
        import_data()
    except Exception as error:
        rollback = True
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        sys.stdout.write("Import canceled\n")
        rollback = True
    if rollback is True:
        transaction.rollback()
    # save history of import
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`TransactionTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase) which handles setup and teardown differently then the normal `TestCase`.

Comment: Awesome - thanks so much! The documentation around transactions doesn't mention how to properly test.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/